# Spacewalk: Unable to add red hat channel and sync the packages

Tags: redhat

I am trying to setup a Red Hat channel for the spacewalk software to support automation of obtaining the patch metadata for RHEL system.I have a subscription of Red hat network but I don't seem to find the documentation for setting up the channel. Please help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have any error on oracle side regarding tablespace.

You can check the error in the below location

```
/opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/spwalk/spwalk/trace
```

error message example:

> unable to extend index SPACEWALK.RHN_PACKAGE_FILE_PID_CID_UQ by 1024 in tablespace SPACEWALK